# Как разбить строку с тегами по разделителю?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте вопросов и ответов есть поле для ввода тегов, например

Теги:

```
игры, gta, скачать, торрент
```

Как разбить строку по разделителю (запятая) с получением в массив всех тегов, их начальных позиций и длин, например

```
var tags = [
    [игры, 0, 4],
    [gta, 6, 3],
    [скачать, 12, 7],
    [торрент, 21, 7]
]
```

Как это сделать более красиво?

Comment: Строка - `var str = 'игры, gta, скачать, торрент';`
`var tags = str.split(', ').map(function(e) {
  return [e, str.indexOf(e), e.length];
});` - массив.

Comment: @entithat в общем случае работать будет, но на строке `игры, gta, gta V` сомается определение позиции.

Comment: @entithat Извините, немного не  корректный пример привел. Попробуйте выполнить на таком массиве `игры, gta V, gta`, Результат `[["игры",0,4],["gta V",6,5],["gta",6,3]]`

Comment: @entithat я так думаю, что если бы ТС были бы ясны подобные нюансы, то он бы не задавал здесь данного вопроса :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Наша исходная строка
// Сразу проходимся по тэгах
var str = 'игры, gta V, gta, игр';
var tags = str.split(/,\s/).map(function(e) {
  // Берём регулярку для поиска слова
  // Сразу возвращаем каждый тэг с его характеристиками
  // Для позиции использую поз + 1, т.к. ищем слово с пробелом в начале
  var re = new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + e + '(,|$)');
  return [e, str.search(re) + (str.search(re) == 0 ? 0 : 1), e.length];
});

console.log(tags);
```

P.S. Модификация скрипта зависит от изначальной строки: `игры, gta V, gta, игр`, либо если будет `игры,   gta V,      gta, игр`, то поиск и деление на отдельные тэги придется немного изменить.